# Using Fetch to gather information from a Backend API?

Tags: javascript, ruby, vue.js

In my backend (Ruby) I call a translation API, which returns me translated text. I need to then display this translated text when a User clicks on my TranslationButton.vue Component, I don't know to correctly reach into my Backend API via fetch. How does one discover the correct endpoint to use, when we are referring to a backend api call?

Messages.vue

```
methods {
    loadTranslations() {
      fetch('#whatgoeshere')
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(myJson) {
        console.log(myJson)
      });
    },
  }
```

request.rb

```
def make_request
    response = Faraday.post('https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate', auth_key: 'authkeyhere', text: @final_ticket, target_lang: 'DE', source_lang: 'EN')
    if response.status == 200
      body = response.body
      translated_text = body.split('"')[-2]
      return translated_text
    else
      raise InvalidResponseError unless response.success?
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a route setup for your make_request method. Then hit that route from your front end.

i.e. `fetch("localhost:3000/make_request?maybe_some_query_param=whatever_you_are_translating")` and the rest of what you have looks good.